# Styling tooltip using Bootstrap v3.0.2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm using Boostrap v3.0.2 and I want to make tooltip but to style it a bit different. I want to make tooltip background-color black, to have small padding  and to be positioned to the right.

Now, it looks like that:

[image: Tooltip image]

My code is the following:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      });
```

```css
   .tooltip .tooltip-inner {
        max-width: 200px;
        padding: 1px 3px;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #000;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-file" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Remove"></span>
```

I tried to change it in this way, but no change:

```css
.remove-file .tooltip .tooltip-inner {background-color: black !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working well, see demo.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```css
.tooltip .tooltip-inner {
   
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.remove-file {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-file" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="This is Working correctly"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but nothing changes.

Comment: It doesn't chante, I even put `!important`, my custom css is after Bootstrap CSS but it is with background-color: white and is positioned below text.

Comment: @mistery_girl Your snippet code is not working, solve it please.

Comment: Well, I edited it but it's showing error "is not a function", only here it's showing this error.I've included jQuery

Answer (score 0):

First you need to put your external css file below the bootstrap's css file it will then override the default css,then you just need to make the color change in the class as:

```
  .tooltip-inner{
     background:red;
    }
```